# c++ class setter sets variables different when argumentname and variable name are equal

Tags: c++, variables, setter, scoping

I'm completly new to c++ and I found something I don't understand and which I cannot find the answer for(also I'm sure it has been asked a lot, so point me to a thread would also be nice).

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>

    class Car {
        int doors;

        public:
            void set_doors(int doors){
                doors = doors;
            }

            int get_doors(){
                return doors;
            }
    };

    int main()
    {
        Car ford;
        ford.set_doors(3);
        std::cout << ford.get_doors() << std::endl;
    }
```

So when I run the code it returns always an int of length 9.

I know that the issue is happening because in

```
void set_doors(int doors)
```

I'm using the same name for the argument and the variable I'd like to change.
If I would change the code to

```
  void set_doors(int newdoors){
   doors = newdoors;
  }
```

everything will work perfectly.

My question is: 
Why does the code behave like this, when using the name for the variable which I like to modify and the argument name?
Please explain it in an easy way ;)

Thanks

Best

Comment: What do you suppose `doors = doors` does? Do you expect the compiler to know that one `doors` is the function parameter and the other is the member, and which one is which?

Comment: I'm not coming from a language where I did have any relations to a compiler, so this is not obvious ot me. 
So you say, this is happening because the compile does not how to differentiate between those values?

Comment: Compiler or not, how is *anyone* supposed to know which one is which? As a side note, you should probably enable all warnings when you compile.

Comment: The compiler knows exactly how to differentiate between them. It has a rule for it. The local variable (the parameter) hides the non-local variable (the member) It just doesn't know how *you* are expecting them to be differentiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the code behave like this, when using the name for the variable which I like to modify and the argument name?

Because the rules of C++ require it to behave this way: names of local variables and parameters "win" over member variables. You should get a compiler warning on this assignment, saying that the assignment has no effect (it assigns the value of a parameter back to itself).

One of idiomatic ways of resolving this is as follows:

```
this->doors = doors;
```

This is the way the language lets you resolve situations when an unqualified name could refer to more than one thing.

Comment: It "knows how to proceed", but the rules of the compiler says that the nearest definition of a variable takes precedence, meaning that both of your `doors` refer to the same thing - the value passed in. Obviously setting it to itself doesn't cause any problem in itself, but it's not what you wanted.

Comment: @ChristophHa Yes, the compiler has to follow a very specific list of rules to decide what object is referred by an unqualified identifier. Local variables always win over member identifiers, but the language provides you a way to "compensate" for this by qualifying members with `this->`.

Comment: Strange enough, you'll get no compiler warning with MSVC 2013, not even with `/W4`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behaviour, because you attempt to read an uninitialized variable. In the following function:

> ```
> void set_doors(int doors){
>   doors = doors;
> }
> ```

`doors` always refers to the function argument, *not* to the member variable. In other words, you self-assign the function argument and your `doors` member variable is left untouched. What's worse is the member variable is never initialized. Reading it in `get_doors` produces `9` only by sheer coincidence on your machine. The program could just do anything.

You can fix your setter function like this:

```
void set_doors(int doors){
    this->doors = doors;
}
```

Still, your class would be very easy to use incorrectly, because it is not obvious that one should have to call `set_doors` before `get_doors` actually works. You want to initialize `doors` to `0` in the constructor:

```
class Car {
    int doors;

public:
    Car() : doors(0) {}

    void set_doors(int doors){
        this->doors = doors;
    }

    int get_doors(){
        return doors;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Once inside the function get_doors, the argument 'doors' hides the member variable 'doors'. So the assignment 'doors = doors' basically assigns the function parameter doors to doors and the member variable is still left undefined.

Also, I would ideally not design the class this way, I would rather setup the class member variables in the constructor.

   ***

- Class Car {
        int doors;    public:
        Car(int doors): doors(doors) {}
        int get_door_count(){ return doors; }    };

*

Notice that in this case the compiler can correctly differentiate between the function argument doors and the member variable doors when using the member initialiser syntax.